# How can I notify the parent page when a popup has finished a load which the parent initated?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

My main HTML page does the following:

```
var popup = window.open(...);
// Wait for popup to load
popup.onload = function() { do_something(); };
popup.location = "new-page.html";
```

I'd like `do_something` to be called when `new-page.html` is finished loading.  But what I currently have doesn't work -- `do_something` is never called.

How can I make this work?

I only care about getting this to work in Firefox 3.5, if that makes things easier.

Comment: :)  I'm not using this on a production website; I in fact need this to work so I can test a patch I'm writing for Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use window.opener.<functionName> and put your notification code within that function on the parent page

Comment: Beware of window.opener. It's proprietary IE, and not part of any standards recommendation, and people have had problems with this in firefox:codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=44015

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the opener object?

http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html

Answer (score 1):

Or, without messing with the HTML of the child window, from the parent, you can attach a listener on the load event of the iframe.  In this solution, i am going to use jQuery for simplicty, but any library or even manual event attachment will do.

In the parent's HTML:

```
<iframe id="foo"></iframe>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var element = $("#foo");
    element.load( function( eventObject ) { 
        // do something here
    } );
    // Now that the event listener is attached, we can set the source.
    element[0].src = "foo.html";

</script>
```

Note, I have not tried setting the source first and then attaching the listener, I am not sure if this would be guaranteed to always work.  It could happen that the iframe is created/loaded before the load listener is attached, I am not sure.  But, by setting the src after the listener is attached, I am sure that the load listener will be called.

Shane

http://www.shanetomlinson.com

http://www.ubernote.com

Comment: I'm curious if you can get this to work without jQuery and with a popup instead of an iframe.  This is basically what I was trying to do in the example I originally gave, but I couldn't make it work.  (IIRC, I was able to make it work by setting `iframe.onload = do_something`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try having the doSomething method called in the popup's onload. You can refer back to the parent by using window.opener

Answer (score 0):

In your .html that is loaded you could have a simple one liner at the end that calls a function on the opening window (if it exists)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (window.opener && window.opener.do_something) window.opener.do_something(window);
</script>
```